# Issue with time differences in ms

Tags: android, datetime

In my app, I am displaying `Notification` with **last opened date** of my application.

This is my code for getting last opened time,

```
long time = 0;
if (MainPageActivity.SettingsInfo != null)
     time = System.currentTimeMillis() - MainPageActivity.SettingsInfo.getLong("LASTOPEN", 0);
```

And getting the difference by,

```
 String getTime(long ms)
    {
        final int SECOND = 1000;
        final int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
        final int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
        final int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
        String text;
        if (ms > DAY) {
            text=(ms / DAY)+(" Day(s) ago");
        }
        else
            text=(ms / HOUR)+(" Hour(s) ago");

        return text;
    }
```

It works fine. But sometimes **it shows 0 hour(s) ago or some irrelevant days like 1250 day(s) ago.**

I am sure that SettingsInfo is not null and has the last opened info when this code runs.

I am using `alarm` where I used above code. The `notification` will be displayed every day if the difference is more than 3 days.

```
 SettingsInfo.edit().putLong("LASTOPEN", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
```

Can anyone solve this? Help me!

Comment: no idea as why you are getting those `1250 day(s) ago` but instead of your current calculations use one of `DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString()` method

Comment: I will try it ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try Catch this,**

```
try
{ 
    SettingsInfo.edit().putLong("LASTOPEN", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // Device couldn't provide time :p 
}
```

and is it okay for else statement with no "{ }" ? (just curious)

Comment: in else case, I am displaying "Long time ago". My problem is _ sometime the difference is wrong and shows irrelevant days_ . And `SettingsInfo.edit().putLong("LASTOPEN", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();` will not throw any exception

Comment: but reading the time wrong could be the only possible reason for it to happen, though I know very little.

Does System.currentTimeMillis() throws exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, you are getting **0 Hour(s) ago** because you are dividing `long` by `int` and if you open your app
before 1 hour is completed since last open, you will always get 0 Hour(s) ago.

Further, as pointed by @pskink
you can use [`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long)) to get relative timespan as:

```
String getTime(long lastOpen) {
    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(lastOpen, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS).toString();
}
```

**lastOpen**: the time stored in `MainPageActivity.SettingsInfo.getLong("LASTOPEN", 0)`

Comment: It works.I will let you know if it works for particular days. But I need DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS and DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS if the hours is >24 and >30*24.

Comment: And I have got _1 Jan 1970_ after one hr if I used MINUTE_IN_MILLIS

Comment: Make sure you are **not** passing `time = System.currentTimeMillis() - MainPageActivity.SettingsInfo.getLong("LASTOPEN", 0);` You just need to pass the lastOpen time, not the time difference.

Comment: Then somehow it got 0 as `lastOpen`

Comment: Is there any common value like DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS which will detect and use the best time minutes/hours/days or week

Comment: I didn't get it. The last parameter is minimum resolution, as `DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS` will give result minimum to 0 minutes.