# How to get the time(freshness value) of ANY app from the time it was launched previously?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the freshness value for any app, i.e the time from which it was launched before. For that I am calculating the time as given by code below inside the *onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)* function of *MyBroadcastReceiver* class.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
String[] dateandtime= formattedDate.split(" ");
String mydate = dateandtime[0];
String mytime = dateandtime[1];
Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

After this I store the info in the SQL database at the end of the function as below

```
        MyDatabaseHelper myDb;
        myDb = new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
        boolean r = myDb.insertData(mytime,lat ,lon , mydate,  weekday, myNetwork, nameWIFI , audiojack, powersaver, appfullname );
        if(r == true){
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"data not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I want to get the time difference from the time the app was launched before to when it was launched again. Can you tell me how to go about doing this ?

Comment: One method was create a global variable and update the values of the app and use this time to subtract from the current time when the app launches again. But here i would have to store the time for all the apps from which I'm receiving broadcast signal from, which is  unknown.

Comment: You should capture time in `Application.class` or in `Main Activity`. You can store time in millis as `System.currentTimeMillis()` and whenever you want to do any manipulation you can do.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal I wanted to catch time when a Broadcast signal occurs so, putting it in Main Activity would be useless to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Get the system time
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Store latest time in DB;
    storeTime(currentTime);
    getTimeDiff(currentTime);
}

private storeTime(time) {
    // Insert in DB
}

private long getTimeDiff(currentTime) {
    long previousTime = <Fetch earlier saved data if any>;
    return currentTime - previousTime; // this will return you milliseconds
}
```

Comment: Okay as per your comment, so you can do the above in your `receiver`

Comment: But  System.currentTimeMillis() sometimes [makes issues as I noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605440/issue-with-time-differences-in-ms)

Comment: This will give time when my app is launched. But as i was trying to tell , i wanted time difference (freshness value) of ANY app when they are launched. That is why I am using BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: There will be no direct method to do that I guess, you have to run a background `Thread` in which you monitor which `activity` and so which app is on top and there you can save a log of transition of apps

Comment: you may require `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />`

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal As i have changed the binaries i have the necessary permission to receive signals when an app is opened.I use  `IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.sec.android.intent.action.GET_LAUNCH");` to perform this.